# How to wrap content of div and add … at the end?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, text, word-wrap

I've a `div` which displays content. My requirement is if it exceeds 10 characters it must show

```
10 characters + '...'
```

I can use jQuery as well as PHP.

Answer (score 1):

To restrict text shown to only, and specifically, 10 characters will be tricky as you'll need to calculate text width based on font settings.

If you use an unit like em you won't need to bother this and the text shown will be almost the same width you desire.

There is an editable example of this:

http://jsfiddle.net/flaviocysne/88nLY/2/

Based on these sites examples:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html

http://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis

Answer (score 0):

If you use php you can use the function **substr($text, $start, $length)**, the doc [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) like this:

```html
<?php

$test = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisici";
// fonction to split the part of text if necessary
$result = strlen($test)>10 ? substr($test, 0, 10).'....': $test;
// to display the text: and don't check the length of string
echo $result;
```

so in jQuery , you have too fonction **substr** the doc : [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) 
like that:

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
 let text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisici"
 let result = text.length > 10 ? text.substr(0, 10)+"..." : text;
 
 alert(result);
});
```

I hope it's help you